# The command http://localhost:8383/wd/hub/session is not recognized by the server

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, composer-php, phpstorm

I am working on an automated functional unit testing in PHP. I want to run a test on staging environment using PhpStorm and I am following this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/. I have complete tasks up-to this code :

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Developer4
 * Date: 11/2/2016
 * Time: 1:41 PM
 */
class uatTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(8383);
        $this->setBrowserUrl('https://www.facebook.com/');

        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    }
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->stop();
    }
    public function validInputsProvider()
    {
        $inputs[] = [
            [
                'email'              => 'hnuat',
                'pass'              => 'pass'
            ]
        ];

        return $inputs;
    }
    public function testFormSubmissionWithUsername()
    {
        $this->byName('email')->value('hnuat');
        $this->byId('loginbutton')->submit();
        $email = $this->byName('email');
        $this->assertEquals('hnuat', $email->value());
    }
}
```

Test Output is:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:/wamp/www/PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration uatTest C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\test\uatTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 7:31 PM ...
PHPUnit 5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


The command http://localhost:8383/wd/hub/session is not recognized by the server.
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php:133
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php:72
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\SessionStrategy\Isolated.php:67
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:296
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:337
 C:\wamp\www\PHPUnit-and-Composer-Workflow\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-selenium\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase.php:314



Time: 4.12 seconds, Memory: 3.00MB


ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

My wamp configuration is localhost:8383/
Any help to solve this issue?